# Drawing a plane in tikz in 3D with a sine wave

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I am trying to draw a plane with the front edge having a sine wave.

Using the code from [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126019/drawing-a-plane-in-3d-space) I can draw it by something like

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,tdplot_main_coords]
    \filldraw[draw=red,fill=red!20
    ]          (0,0,-0.5)
            -- (0,1,-0.5)
            -- (0,1,1)
            -- (0,0,1)
            -- (0,{0.1*sin(deg(4*pi*0.975)},0.975)
            -- ...lots more points....
            -- (0,{0.1*sin(deg(4*pi*-0.475)},-0.475)
            -- cycle;
    \draw[thick,->] (0,-0.2,0) -- (0,1.2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x$};
    \draw[thick,->] (0,0,-0.5) -- (0,0,1.2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
    \draw[thick,->] (-0.5,0,0) -- (1.2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

where I specify all the points on the sine curve manually. There must be a better way of doing this, for example something like

```
--[domain=1:-0.5] (0,{0.1*sin(deg(4*pi*x)},x)
```

I've attached my results so far doing it manually. I want to be able to vary the sine wave which is why I want a better way of doing it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it. See the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{70}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
    \draw [red, fill=red!20, domain=-.5:1, samples=100] plot (0,{.1*sin(deg(4*pi*\x))},\x) -- (0,1,1) -- (0,1,-.5) -- cycle;

    \begin{scope}[->, shorten >= 2mm]
        \draw (-.5,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node {$y$};
        \draw (0,-.5,0) -- (0,2,0) node {$x$};
        \draw (0,0,-.5) -- (0,0,2) node {$z$};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: rendered image]

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you use an actual function instead of drawing it manually step by step.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{70}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,tdplot_main_coords]

\fill[draw=red, fill=red!20, variable=\z,domain=-.5:1,samples=200] 
    (0,0,-.5) plot (0,{sin(\z*pi r*4)/10},\z)
    -- (0,1,1)
    -- (0,1,-0.5)
    -- cycle;

\draw[thick,->] (0,-0.2,0) -- (0,1.2,0) node[anchor=north west]{$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0,-0.5) -- (0,0,1.2) node[anchor=south]{$z$};
\draw[thick,->] (-0.5,0,0) -- (1.2,0,0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works just as well as the other answer. I marked the other one as correct because the code was slightly clearer.